# Testing controller on CakePHP2.0 which calls model functions

Tags: cakephp, testing, model, controller, cakephp-2.0

This is my test:

```
public function testIncludeNumComment() {
    $post = array(...stuff.....);
    $result = $this->Comments->includeNumComments($post);
    echo "end"; //this is not printed
    $expected =1;

    $this->assertEquals($result, $expected);
}
```

Then, my controller function is this one:

```
public function includeNumComments($post){
        echo "printed";
    $comments = $this->Comment->getNumComments($post['Post']['id']);
    echo "not printed";

    return $comments;
}
```

As you can see, this call on the controller to the model function doesn't work

```
$this->Comment->getNumComments($idPost);
```

And what is more, when i introduce an **echo "hi";** at the very start of the **getNumComments** function inside the Comment model, it is not printed either. 
It's like it didn't find the function or something like that. (but it doesn't show any error by screen during the test)

It stops there and it doesn't execute more code.
I am completely sure that function works well, it just returns the number of comments from a post. The question is: why it isn't working on the test case?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
The test setUp looks like this:

```
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->Comments = new TestCommentsController();
    $this->Comments->constructClasses();

}
```

Comment: The core (>=2.0) now hides output by default. but it also contains a way to enable debugging output for your tests again. You need to append &debug=1 to the url in your test suite (another solution is mentioned at http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/04/unit-testing-tips-for-2-0-and-phpunit/).

Comment: I have done it now. I don't see any change. It still doesn't show the prints inside getNumComments function on the model.

Comment: typo? why `$this->Comments->` instead of the correct `$this->Comment->`?

Comment: Cake Bake command created the test like that. CommentsController, Comment model and Comments view is my structure.

Comment: I have just updated the question for you to see how the setUp is defined in the test case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $this->Comments->includeNumComments($post);
```

this doesnt make much sense if your model is "Comment"

so change it to:

```
$result = $this->Comment->includeNumComments($post);
```

Comment: The test is not calling the model, the test is calling the controller. I am testing the controller. And then, the controller calls the model with this function: getNumComments

Comment: ah i see - sry, that wasn't clear to me before. your controller methods looks pretty strange, though. it shouldnt return this array but render some view for it. maybe that is related in some way.

Comment: It doesn't render any view, it is just a function to return data to another one.

Comment: ok, you are new to cake: you should either make it protected then (_include...) or the better way here: make this a model method. it shouldnt be in the controller here anyway. only "visible" actions should be there.

Comment: I can not made it a model method because it operates with the array modifying it. It is not just a query to return. So, where should i write it then? I thought controllers were the logic of the application... and that's what my function is: logic.

Comment: i still put it into the model. because it could be used inside other model methods as well, or from shell/cli etc. so better to keep it dry (fat model, slim controller)

Comment: Anyway, this doesn't solve the problem i have every time a controller calls a model.

Comment: have you any more information on what exactly happens? there must be some error occuring (and a message along with it). make sure you are in debug mode (test cases are always in debug mode of course).

Comment: Ok, i have solved it. I didn't have the var $uses = array('Comment'); on the Comments controller. It worked perfectly well and it didn't show any error but it seems necessary after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that you include the `TestCommentsController` like following:

```
App::uses('TestCommentsController', 'Controller');
```

Then write `beforeFilter` function in `AppController` like following:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    ......
    ...
    public function beforeFilter() {
      // you stuff
    }
}
```

Then add this to you controller which contains `test` function:

```
    public function beforeFilter(){
       parent::beforeFilter();
       $this->Comments = new TestCommentsController();
       $this->Comments->constructClasses();
   }

.....
```

NOW keep going with...

```
   public function testIncludeNumComment() {
      $post = array(...stuff.....);
      $result = $this->Comments->includeNumComments($post);
      echo "end"; //this is not printed
      $expected =1;

      $this->assertEquals($result, $expected);
  }
```

Comment: Where should i place the App::uses? in what file? CommentsControllerTest?

And the beforeFilter function? In what class?

Comment: @Steve which controller contains the test function?

Comment: App/Test/Cases/Controller/CommentsControllerTest.php
There are 2 classes inside: TestCommentsController and CommentsControllerTestCase. The tests are in 
The class CommentsControllerTestCase

Comment: It seems it doesn't work. I have the function beforeFilter at TestCommentsController and the rest is everything like you say.